# UIActivityIndicatorView in the same hierarchy of UITableView in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UIViewController and I dropped a UITableView and UIActivityIndicatorView in the same hierarchy and it's working fine.

But then I have a UITableViewController, with a UITableView of course, and I try to drop a UIActivityIndicatorView at the same hierarchy as the Table View but with no luck. I know that there's a problem with UITableViewController and UIViewController with Table View but how to solve?

These two screenshots will help to understand the problem.

The way I want it to be:

[image]

The way it turns out:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with the `UIViewController` it has a `self.view` as the root view where you can add any sub-items as you did , put you can't do this at least in IB with `UITableViewController`  as the root view is the table itself

**First way**

add it in code and control is position as the tableView scrolls so change it's frame in `scrollViewDidScroll` so it's stay at center of screen during the loading

**Second way**

add it to the main window of the app and remove it when loading finishes

Comment: First way did worked but too much typing :)
Secondway didn't worked, may be I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you drag and drop any view (no matter if it is **UILabel** or **UIActivityIndicatorView** or **UIView**),

if it is **above** the cell you put there, it will be treated as the **TableViewHeader** automatically.

if it is **below** the cell you put there, it will be treated as the **TableViewFooter** automatically.

That is the reason why they are at the same level of view hierarchy of cells.

If you really want to use the `indicatorView` at same level as your `tableView` in your `tableViewController`, even if you programmatically create it and add it to your `tableviewcontroller`'s `self.view`, it **WILL NOT** work, because `tableViewController`'s `self.view` is its content view, which is scrollable anyways, which is kinda a bummer. We only have full control in `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, guys I found one more solution.

Define a variable inside `UITableViewController`

```
weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

then in `viewDidLoad` method make this (hope the code is self explanatory)

```
let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
tableView.backgroundView = activityIndicatorView
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
self.spinner = activityIndicatorView
```

and then call `spinner.startAnimating()` when you need to show it, and

```
self.spinner.stopAnimating()
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
```

to remove it when you don't need it.